# Interpreting garage door sensor signal using a microcontroller/opamp

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

Edit 3: I had more information to share regarding my question.

I am trying to use this [garage door sensor](http://www.digi-code.com/sensor.html) in one of my projects. I am trying to use the sensor to detect if a person tripped the sensor. There is really no documentation for the sensor except for the [patent information](http://www.google.com/patents/US6020703.pdf).

The sensor has two terminals '+' and '-'. I was able to read the data from the '+' line. The sensor is powered by a 12V source and the response is a square wave that I was able to capture by turning on the AC coupling. [image]

As seen from the capture, the signal is really noisy. When there is no beam interruption, the output is a square wave while there is none when the beam is interrupted. How do I detect a square wave of such a small amplitude?

Comment: Any reason you don't just use the oscilloscope to do the AC coupling for you? As in, probe the output of the sensor with the oscilloscope directly and then use the meter's AC coupling option...

Comment: @Shamtam I am not sure I understood that but my goal is to put the sensor to use in a product as a low cost safety sensor

Comment: The first thing to do is to get rid of that capacitor and show us what the sensor output really looks like. Since it spiked down, then up in the top picture, we can infer that those two events may have been the edges of a simple low level. Turning that into two glitches just makes things harder. Also, if there are two outputs, show us both of them. Possibly the signal is differential, so show the "+" output minus the "-" output too. That may be the real signal.

Comment: The signal appears a glitch even without a capacitor. I included a picture of the same. I tried differential signal measurement. It was just noise on the '-' line

Comment: You oscilloscope has a switch that selects between DC/GND/AC for each input. When you select the AC coupling then a capacitor is used in series with the signal (internally) and removes the DC offset.

Comment: @alexan_e Oh I did use the AC coupling.

Comment: Then there is no need for the external capacitor. By the way, your image shows a DC offset of around 12v, are you sure you have used AC mode?

Comment: @alexan_e The last capture was using DC coupling but I did use AC coupling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick read of the patent, my first thoughts were confirmed: the sensor expects to receive a periodic train of pulses that cease when the beam is interrupted.  The receiver can be as simple as a retriggerable monostable timer.  This would be straightforward to implement in a microcontroller, particularly one with a built-in comparator.

- Run a tick timer in the background that fires an interrupt every 1ms.
- Use the comparator to trigger an interrupt every time a pulse is detected from the receiver.
- Tick timer interrupts increment a counter; comparator interrupts reset the same counter.
- If the counter reaches a reasonable value, say 100, then the beam has been interrupted; take action appropriately (set an output high, for example).

Comment: Should I use a peak detecting opamp circuit? I had no luck converting the peaks into logic output using the opamp

Comment: You shouldn't need to unless the pulses aren't wide enough to cause your choice of monostable to retrigger.